# jquery append pushing inline li down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm probably missing something glaringly obvious, however I can't for the life of me figure it out. On list icon hover, the text displays in an "output" li that should be in-line with the rest, except it keeps on getting pushed down and I can't figure out why
full code and demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/YbN8D/1/

```
        <ul id="social8">
            <li id="facebook" class="social8icon"></li>
            <li id="raptr" class="social8icon"></li>
            <li id="social8output"></li>


        </ul>
```

*

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $("#facebook").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#social8output").append("Facebook");
    });
    $("#raptr").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#social8output").append("Raptr");
    });
    $(".social8icon").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#social8output").empty();
    });

});
```

*

```
body {
font-family: 'Century Gothic';
font-size: '10px';
}
#social8 li {
    display: inline-block;

    list-style: none;
}
.social8icon {
 background: #000;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
}
#social8output {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 120px;
    background: #ff0000;
    font-size: 8px;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to the #social8 li class

```
#social8 li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    list-style: none;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/YbN8D/7/)**

Comment: accepting this one as it doesn't require farting about with clearfixing or setting margins. I knew it was something simple I'd overlooked >.<

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/YbN8D/3/

```
#social8 li {
    float: left;
}
```

as you'll notice that gets them all on the same line

however, it does put them all together instead of that tiny margin you had. So to get that back like you want I added

```
#social8output {
    margin: 0 2px;
}

.social8icon {
    margin: 0 2px;
}
```

and updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YbN8D/6/

Comment: Gad damnit, I knew it would be an obvious one. I'm off to go shoot myself!